# What "scaling" means in the "muma" package of R?

Tags: r

I want to perform the OPLS-DA using the "muma" package in R. But when I ran codes for listig variables in the dataset, some problems happened. There is nothing happened after the operation. The codes I used was listed following:

```
function (scaling)
{
  pwd.n = paste(getwd(), "/Preprocessing_Data_", scaling,   "/ProcessedTable.csv",
            sep = "")
  x <- read.csv(pwd.n, sep = ",", header = TRUE)
  x.x <- x[, 2:ncol(x)]
  rownames(x.x) <- x[, 1]
  print(colnames(x.x))
}
```

Then I ran this code. I got a error message that object "scaling" not found. The reference manual explains the scaling as a character. So, why it cannot be found? How to solve this problem? Thank you very much!

```
pwd.n = paste(getwd(), "/Preprocessing_Data_", scaling, "/ProcessedTable.csv",
            sep = "")
  x <- read.csv(pwd.n, sep = ",", header = TRUE)"
```

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Based on your above code, that's just a text/character/string variable that you are using to set a file path to read some password file.

Comment: I had thought the "/Preprocessing_Data_" was my directory, and the "/ProcessedTable.csv" was my dataset which could be read directly. But now I can't read my own data still. pwd.n is not found.